# How to add column for previous visits in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns (visir_id, patient_id, and date)

I need to add a column called previous_visit that shows the date of the patients previous visit. I am completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Is there a way to get the new previous_visit column to autopopulate based on patient_id and visit_date data of previous entries?

Comment: Curious, isn't that info already available in the table? You can always check the last visit before a particular visit_id by sorting by date

Comment: Previous visit can easily be obtained in a select query so why do you feel the need to store it? and what do mean by  'autopopulate with an aggragate'? You could clarify by publishing sample data and desired outcome as text together with the version of mysql you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add the column previous_visit before visit_id column, write:

```
alter table table_name add previous_visit date first;
```

Next may be create a trigger,

```
create trigger ti_visit_date before insert on table_name for each row set new.previous_visit=(select max(visit_date) from table_name);
```

and then insert script into table_name.

Comment: Is there a way to program the previous_visit column to autopopulate with an aggragate based on the patient_id and the visit_date of previous visits?

Comment: May be create a trigger,

Comment: **create trigger ti_visit_date before insert on table_name for each row set new.previous_visit=(select max(visit_date) from table_name);**  next insert into table_name with the values.